# how to integrate (x-1)/(x+1)

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the integral $$\int\frac{x-1}{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ I have tried solving it by differentiating the denominator and substituting it, but I didn't get it. How else can I solve it?

Comment: First, do the division.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: $$\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Comment: @HighZedd $$\frac{x-1}{x+1} = \frac{x+1-2}{x+1} = 1-\frac2{x+1}$$

Comment: $\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1-2}{x+1}=1-\frac{2}{x+1}$

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x-1}{x+1}\ dx &= \int\frac{x+1-2}{x+1}\ dx\\
&= \int\left(1-\frac2{x+1}\right)\ dx\\
&= \int dx - 2\int\frac{dx}{x+1}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$